# Filtering JSON data with filter function in React- Redux

Tags: json, reactjs, filter

I have a JSON file with the following format:

```
const data = [
  {
    "quantity": "200",
    "prodType": "stock",
    "symbol": "LOL",
    "prodDesc": "Εθνική τράπεζα",
    "market": "Greece",
    "averageCost": "131,16",
    "totalCost": "123,47",
    "lastPrice": "121,123",
    "value": "123,34",
    "positionPercentage": "10",
    "valueEUR": "113,23",
    "pl": "1300",
    "plPercentage": "12",
    "plEuro": "1238",
    "results": "12-01-2017",
    "dividend": "12-03-2017",
    "isin": "1234566"
  }
]
```

I want to filter the data using their Product Type.
As a result, im creating an action

```
export function fetchSearchData(product_type) {
  const filtered_data = data.filter(record=>
    {
        return record.prodType.match(product_type)
    });

  return {
    type: FETCH_SEARCH_DATA,
    payload: filtered_data
  };
}
```

But it does not seem to work. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `match` will match the string against a regular expression, try this for equality check: `return record.prodType === product_type`